# how do you get the pitch of a triangle to get higher or lower?

Tags: percussion, pitch

how to get the pitch of a triangle higher or lower?

Comment: You play it in a fast moving vehicle, while going past the listener.

Comment: Blobby are you asking if it's possible and how to permanently change the apparent pitch of a musical triangle?

Comment: Are we talking isosceles or scalene, 'cos you can't alter the pitch of an equilateral...

Comment: You can't change the _pitch_, but it's possible to get a _tremolo_ effect by flapping your hand in the space in the middle of the triangle.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

You can Tune a triangles pitch by shortening the space on the bottom part that you strike, with electric tape. (See photo)  This will raise the pitch, my triangle has an unaltered pitch of B, using tape I now have one side tuned to C (blue) and the other side tuned to G.  It seems the area of exposed surface (no tape) on the bottom side determines the pitch, so for G, I had to raise the pitch 5 steps, thus the tape on both sides of the bar.  This is easiest to do if you can match the pitch with your voice or another instrument, a tuner won’t get it so you need a pretty good ear. So now my triangle plays in C or G depending which way I hold it.  I also have tape across the outside bar only to mute the instrument a bit, as my triangle is very loud.  I actually stumbled upon this this evening trying to mute my triangle and quickly discovered it changed the pitch, went to see if anyone else knew about this and it appears not, so happy to share a new discovery, happy playing out there!

Answer (score 3):

I know this might be stupid, but check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic

> "On stringed instruments, harmonics are played by touching (but not fully pressing down the string) at an exact point on the string while sounding the string (plucking, bowing, etc.); this allows the harmonic to sound, a pitch which is always higher than the fundamental frequency of the string."

I haven't found anything on how idiophones vibrate, but i believe for a triangle it would be a transversal wave like a guitar string. With luck you may be able to hold it at any harmonic node to make a higher tone. Note that it will in that case sound muted and weak.

Also, to tune a triangle higher just remove material from the ends. Dunno why you would want this though.

Answer (score 3):

In order to change the pitch of a triangle you would need to change its mass. You could make the triangle flatter or sharper by making it larger or smaller respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question! There are actually a few ways you can do so, both permanent and non permanent. The easiest would be to play the triangle in various positions. Try playing in the center of one side and compare to the sound of playing in the corner. You can also try playing in the center of the whole bar verses near one of the ends. The next easiest is changing your striking stick. A heavier, thicker rod will sound a bit lower than a thinner, shorter rod. Different materials sound slightly different as well. Note that both of these methods won't produce a huge difference in sound. The only way to radically change its pitch is to alter the length or thickness of the body, and at that point you're better off investing in another triangle.

Comment: No matter what you hit it _with_ or _where_ you hit it, a triangle will have the same perceived pitch.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS Triangles don't generally have a perceived frequency in the way you describe. The triangle will have the same *fundamental frequency*, but by hitting it in different places, you can actually control the relationship between the volumes of the many nonharmonic overtones a triangle produces, thus slightly changing the perceived sound (and potentially the perceived frequency). It's analogous to dialing in a tone on an electric guitar - the fundamental is the same, but you can change the ratios of volumes of the overtones to control the sound.

Answer (score 2):

You can partially submerge it in a tub of water.  As more of the triangle is under water, the pitch will change.

Answer (score 0):

All sources I checked say that the triangle is of indefinite pitch.  For example, the Percussive Arts Society has a fact sheet: https://www.pas.org/docs/default-source/pasic-archives/triangle.

You can get different effects from different size triangles, and with different playing techniques, but apparently it is not possible to change the pitch as such, given that there is no pitch as such.

(This is very different from another percussion instrument, the chimes.  How many times have we heard the chimes come in sounding completely out of tune in relation to the rest of the ensemble.)

---

Here's another attempt:

The triangle doesn't have a pure pitch. It's a bit like banging a pot or a piece of scrap metal. But some triangles are higher and some are lower, and once it's been produced, the highness or lowness can't be changed.

Also some sound more beautiful than others.  Generally the more beautiful sounding ones cost a lot more.

Comment: Indefinite pitch does not mean no pitch.  A larger triangle is clearly lower in pitch than a smaller one.

Comment: @phoog - so it's a collection of frequencies?  Interesting.  But isn't the pitch of the triangle defined at birth, so to speak?  With no way of being adjusted?

Comment: "a collection of frequencies": so is the tone of a violin.  It's just that the ear does not resolve it into a definite pitch as it does with a violin.  The pitch is more or less defined at birth, yes.  You can make it higher by filing it down (reducing its mass or length) or lower I suppose by clamping weights to the ends.

Comment: @aparente001 The higher partials produced on a vibrating stiff bar are not multiples of the lowest frequency - see https://www.phys.uconn.edu/~gibson/Notes/Section4_1/Sec4_1.htm. So the perceived "pitch" of a triangle, which is weakly fixed about one-third of its length, isn't well determined. Vibrating strings have much better behaved partials.

Comment: @phoog - and ...

Comment: @Peter - So the answer by heck is the best so far?

Comment: @Peter but bells also have non-integral partials, yet they are perceived to have a definite pitch.  Why is that?

Comment: ...and therefore the statement "it is not possible to change the pitch as such, given that there is no pitch as such" is not correct.

Comment: @phoog Bells are very complicated. They're more like lates which have a totally different set of partials. Also, they're  not uniformly thick, which makes the maths far more complicated, if soluble at all. Bell-casting is an art. Also, bells have more than one pitch. There's the pitch when you strike it, and the hum tone which resonates when all the higher-pitched partials have faded out. And a lod of other partials as well. If these have a good harmonic relationship it's sweet-toned, If not,  it can be very clangy. That's the extent of my knowledge of bells.

Comment: @phoog There's no real pitch to a triangle, but the effect is still higher or lower depending on the length, diameter and metal. I once had to play percussion in a piece that asked for 6 triangles of different pitches. And the smallest one didn't have the highest perceived pitch. No idea why.

Comment: @aparente001 Seems like it. But Brian THOMAS has some good points too. It looks as is a conclusion has been collectively reached. And some good jokes as well.

Comment: @Peter - The only thing I could find from Brian is "No matter what you hit it with or where you hit it, a triangle will have the same perceived pitch."  Well, does it or doesn't it have a perceived *pitch*?  Look, I'm going to try to forget everything I've read here for a moment and just try to say something based on my own experience of triangles.  See what you think: The triangle doesn't have a pure pitch.  It's a bit like banging a pot or a piece of scrap metal.  But some are higher and some are lower, and once it's been produced, the highness or lowness can't be changed.

Comment: @aparente001 Oops sorry, I think I meant to say user45266 which was an answer to Brian. I agree with your last comment 100%.

Comment: @Peter - I've revised my answer, see what you think.

Comment: @aparente001 I'd say that a triangle has better tone than most pots. Possibly they have fewer partials due to being essentially one-dimensional. I can't comment on the relative beauty of percussion instruments - that is in the ear of the beholder..

Comment: @Peter - well, I hope there's some justification for charging the big bucks for the expensive ones.

Comment: @aparente001 No idea. Never bought one.